# How to get pylint working in spyder

Tags: python, pylint, spyder

I'm new to python prorgamming. I'm having trouble with getting pylint to work i spyder. I have managed to install pylint in spyder and i get the pylint window in spyder. The problem is that i can't seem to open any files in the pylint window if I try to do so, the file I have chosen will not show In the pylint window the message "Pylint script was not found. Please add C:\pytnon27\scripts to PATH".

Comment: Spyder dev here :) How did you install Pylint? The problem seems that Spyder can't find the pylint script in your PATH. Please consider using Python(x,y), which is the easiest way to get Spyder and its dependencies correctly installed on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

So have you tried adding C:\python27\scripts to your system path?

Although the tutorial given [here](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html) is quite outdated, you should be able to work things out.

Comment: Not only is the Tutorial outdated, it is 404!